# What's the meaning of these functions: fn()()?

Tags: python, keras

In Convolutional Neural Networks, I've came across some strange functions that take parameters in first parenthesis before taking the input in the second parenthesis.
e.g `Fn(parameters=params)(input=x)`

```
Conv2D(filters = F2, kernel_size = 1, strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid', kernel_initializer = initializer(seed=0))(X)
```

What is this called and why does it exist? Why not simply pass the input in the first part?

Comment: It's a _higher-order function_, a function that returns a function.

Comment: ...or a class that implements `__call__()`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/higher-order-functions-in-python/) **Higher Order Function** is:

> A function is called Higher Order Function if it contains other
> functions as a parameter or returns a function as an output i.e, the
> functions that operate with another function are known as Higher order
> Functions. It is worth knowing that this higher order function is
> applicable for functions and methods as well that takes functions as a
> parameter or returns a function as a result. Python too supports the
> concepts of higher order functions.